# React Native turn off Debug mode and stop displaying warning messages

Tags: react-native

I currently have a scenario where warning messages are turning up on my production app, It is not clear how to turn off these warnings. Anyone know what the Android equivalent is to

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=false"];
```

Comment: Did you follow these steps to build your app? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content

Answer (score 3):

First of all, normally you should bundle your JS if you plan to run the app in production mode, e.g. by running some command like this:

```
node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --dev false --platform ios --entry-file ./index.ios.js --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle
```

To answer your question, the `android/src/main/java/com/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/MainActivity.java` file should contain something like this

```
/**
  * Returns whether dev mode should be enabled.
  * This enables e.g. the dev menu.
  */
  @Override
  protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
  }
```

Which you may change to

```
/**
  * Returns whether dev mode should be enabled.
  * This enables e.g. the dev menu.
  */
  @Override
  protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
    return false;
  }
```

**Edit**: fixed typo

Comment: That is the android solution, just had a typo

Comment: apologies, i read the first line and saw the ios bundling. tried returning false in getUseDeveloperSupport() , no good im afraid, it still shows me warnings

Answer (score 1):

in index.android.bundle file in the assets folder there is an entry

```
(function(global) {global.
    __DEV__=true;
```

set to false and all my issues went away